# What is a subtree (when referring to the DOM in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, dom

What is a subtree (when referring to the DOM in JavaScript)?

I can't seem to find a definition anywhere...

Comment: The DOM as a whole is structured like a *tree*. There's one root (the `<html>` container, and then sub-containers and sub-sub-containers inside that. A *subtree* is just a portion of the DOM tree starting from somewhere inside the larger tree.

Comment: In Simple words,Entire html document is dom and treat as a tree. so basically this is parent child relationship.parent is tree and its nested children is subtree and subtree is tree for its children and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The DOM can be seen as a tree of elements: an element can have many children, but only one parent. The DOM tree tarts with the root: `<html>`. The children of an element can themselves have children. I.e., there can be a tree of elements under an element. Those are called "subtrees."

What a subtree means specifically depends on the context. For example, you can talk about the subtree of a specific `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

The Document Object Model (DOM) is the data representation of the objects that comprise the structure and content of a document on the web.

DOM represented as nested objects, and these nested elements can be viewed as a tree.

According to the data structure of trees based on graph theory:

A `subtree of a tree T` is a tree consisting of a node in T and all of its descendants in T.

So same can be applied to the DOM representation tree, hence subtree of DOM in javascript is itself a tree consisting of a node in DOM and all of its descendants in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, I believe it's a fancy word for the child component and all nested components within it. Check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sub-tree-nodes-tree-using-dfs/) out

<

```
body className='tree'>
    <div className='sub-tree1'>
      <div className='branch1-st1'>
       <p> text </p>
      </div>
      <div className='branch2-st1'>
       <p> text </p>
      </div>
      <div className='branch3-st1'>
       <p> text </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className='sub-tree2'>
      <div className='branch1-st2'>
       <p> text </p>
      </div>
      <div className='branch2-st2'>
       <p> text </p>
      </div>
      <div className='branch3-st2'>
       <p> text </p>
      </div>
</body>
```